# Source of "talent is formed in solitude", attributed to Goethe

Tags: quote-source, johann-wolfgang-von-goethe

I'm annotating an essay by Paul Hensel and he quotes Goethe: "talent is formed in solitude, character in the currents and cataracts of the world." I can't seem to find what the source of this quote is.

Answer (score 3):

In Goethe's 1790 play [Torquato Tasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torquato_Tasso_(play)) (see also [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/19753/19753-h/19753-h.htm)) the character Leonora speaks (act 1, scene 2) the lines "Es bildet ein Talent sich in der Stille /
Sich ein Charakter in dem Strom der Welt".  This can also be translated as "Talent is formed in quiet retreat / Character in the headlong rush of life".

Comment: [*Goethe's Werke* (1828), volume 9, p. 106](https://archive.org/details/goetheswerke135goetgoog/page/n116/mode/2up)

Comment: Travis Berg: if you found this answer helpful to you, please "accept" it by clicking on the icon in the margin.